# How to include a clickable link or button for each record? HTML + Array + Tables

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have learnt a sample code from youtube on putting an array in HTML table dynamically that is sortable. Below is the code.

How do I made each record in display HTML table clickable and call a myFunction()? The myFunction() will then get the value of the Name in the respective row and execute another query.

HTML Part ->

```
<table class="table table-striped">
<tr  class="bg-info">
    <th data-column="name" data-order="desc">Name &#9650</th>
    <th data-column="age" data-order="desc">Age &#9650</th>
    <th data-column="birthdate" data-order="desc">Birthday &#9650</th>
</tr>

<tbody id="myTable">
    
</tbody>
```

the javascript part

```
var myArray = [
    {'name':'Michael', 'age':'30', 'birthdate':'11/10/1989'},
    {'name':'Mila', 'age':'32', 'birthdate':'10/1/1989'},
    {'name':'Paul', 'age':'29', 'birthdate':'10/14/1990'},
    {'name':'Dennis', 'age':'25', 'birthdate':'11/29/1993'},
    {'name':'Tim', 'age':'27', 'birthdate':'3/12/1991'},
    {'name':'Erik', 'age':'24', 'birthdate':'10/31/1995'},
]

$('th').on('click', function(){
    var column = $(this).data('column')
    var order = $(this).data('order')
    var text = $(this).html()
    text = text.substring(0, text.length - 1)

    if(order == 'desc'){
        $(this).data('order', "asc")
        myArray = myArray.sort((a,b) => a[column] > b[column] ? 1 : -1)
        text += '&#9660'

    }else{
        $(this).data('order', "desc")
        myArray = myArray.sort((a,b) => a[column] < b[column] ? 1 : -1)
        text += '&#9650'

    }
    $(this).html(text)
    buildTable(myArray)
})

buildTable(myArray)

function buildTable(data){
    var table = document.getElementById('myTable')
    table.innerHTML = ''
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        var row = `<tr>
                        <td>${data[i].name}</td>
                        <td>${data[i].age}</td>
                        <td>${data[i].birthdate}</td>
                  </tr>`
        table.innerHTML += row


    }
}
```

My Function Call Js part

```
function myFunction() { " wanna get the value of the row if link is click" }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $(document).on("click", "tbody tr", function(){

//if you want name field
   $(this).find("td:nth-child(1)").text();
//if you want age field
       $(this).find("td:nth-child(2)").text();

}); 
i done the myFunction in Jquery, use this code inside your script tag
```

Comment: some clarification. The $(this).text() returns the whole row of data? What If I just need the name field or the age field data?

Comment: it returns each td value , so in that u get all details of the row

Comment: Now i have edited the code, pls check, if you ok with that, accept my answer

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the following *after* you call the `buildTable(myArray)` so the `<tr>` tags can render before you assign them a click event.

```
   $('tr').click(function(){
       var name = $(this).children('td').first().html();
       yourFunction(name);
    });
    
    function yourFunction(name){
       //do things with name here 
    }
```

Also, this assumes that the first `td` will always contain the name. A better implementation would be to refactor the `buildTable` function and give classes to your `td`

Comment: Based on your code above, how can I get the name and age? which is the 2nd child and 3rd?

Comment: you can use css pseudo-selectors to look for $(this).children('td:nth-child(2)') = returns second td. But in all honesty this is hacky code and instead you should modify your buildTable function to render the <td> elements with classes, then look up the class.